# FFMPEG video output size is too long

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, pyffmpeg

I am trying to merge videos in FFmpeg reading through a .txt file, it merges the videos but increases the total timeline. Expected timeline is 2 minutes but after merging the videos the output file has a timeline of 18 hours.I am using the following command in my cmd:

ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4

Comment: What do you mean by "merging"? Concatenation as in your command (results in longer video), or muxing multiple videos into the same file (results into one file, containing multiple video tracks)?

Comment: Yes use can say concatenation of video having a length of 10-15 seconds each, but the output video is too long

Comment: Are there multiple streams inside any file of the source videos (defined in mylist.txt)?

Comment: Yes, it contains the name of videos that are to be concatenated. I am new to FFmpeg read documentation but can't understand that.

Comment: Please provide an `ffprobe [path/to/file]` output from one file in your mylist.txt

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/32597/

Comment: I have provided this path "ffprobe -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mp4" but it still didn't work. It shows this error  "Failed to set value 'copy' for option 'c': Option not found"

Comment: See Gyan's link. All inputs must share those same attributes. I'm guessing you are trying to concatenate arbitrary inputs that have varying attributes. If you need help determining if this is true, then we need to see info about every input listed in `mylist.txt`. Showing the **complete** output of `ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4` will suffice.